# Can I use HTTP PUT for a property?

Tags: rest, http-put

I'm designing an API that will replace one property of a resource "a".

```
{
   "a": {
      "b": "hello",
      "d": "xxx"
   },
   "c": "hello2"
}
```

I have 2 options seem possible:

1. PUT /resources/{id}/a
   In this way, we treat a as a sub-resource. However, it's kinda debatable whether it's a resource or just a property. If it's just a property, is it OK to PUT on a property?
2. PATCH /resources/{id}
   In this way, we can do a "merge-patch" which is my company's current standard. However, for "merge-patch", there is no way to require the user to pass in all the properties, the user is able to skip some properties, he doesn't want to update. We have some polymorphic models. This makes the implementation very hard.

This becomes a hard design question for us. Please shed some light on me!

Comment: Why would you need to require all of the properties that were already validated and accepted/persisted (in case of PUT)?

Comment: @lgorZ I updated the description a little bit, that it's because some models are polymorphic. And the properties for these classes are very different with different validation rules.